# Can't execute query: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, cron

following error after start sheduled cron job for every 10 min :

```
Output from command /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/html/mydomain/_cron/cron.php ..

PHP Notice:  Can't execute query: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`karsi_jiggo`.`user`.`hide_time` - 10)'
UPDATE user SET hide_time=(hide_time-10), last_visit=last_visit WHERE hide_time>0 in /var/www/html/MyDomain/_include/lib/db.php on line 100

Notice: Can't execute query: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`karsi_jiggo`.`user`.`hide_time` - 10)'
UPDATE user SET hide_time=(hide_time-10), last_visit=last_visit WHERE hide_time>0 in /var/www/html/MyDomain/_include/lib/db.php on line 100
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your output, it looks like there is data in your DB where hide_time is >0 but <10, such that when you attempt to subtract 10 from hide_time, it becomes a negative number and out of bounds for an unsigned int.

To troubleshoot you could

```
SELECT * from user
WHERE hide_time > 0
AND hide_time < 10
```

Comment: here is live of my cron.php how can i correct it ? if ($min % 1 == 0) {
    DB::execute("UPDATE user SET hide_time=(hide_time-10), last_visit=last_visit WHERE hide_time>0");

Comment: The safest way to change it is to alter the where clause to be `WHERE hide_time>10`, that way it will never attempt to convert it to a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Your query;

```
UPDATE user SET hide_time=(hide_time-10), last_visit=last_visit WHERE hide_time>0
```

...will happily try to set hide_time to `-5` if it's `5` at the start of the query (hide_time>0 selects against the *old* value, not the updated value)

`BIGINT UNSIGNED` cannot hold negative values, therefore the error.